# sum two values of dimension but show the result only in one of them in PowerPivot / DAX

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerpivot, dax

It might be a easy one but I cannot solve it so please advice.

I would like to add up two months in a measure (like the current and the previous one) but when I represent the figure in a pivot table I want to show the result only in a current month.

Here is the formula I tried:

```
CALCULATE([Revenue],FILTER(Tbl_Period,Tbl_Period[Month_nr] = 3)) +CALCULATE([Revenue],FILTER(Tbl_Period,Tbl_Period[Month_nr] = 4))
```

But logically when I represent it in pivot table the revenue is appear under the two months:

**See the picture of the result of the below formula:**

[image]

What I want to achieve instead is the following:

**See the picture of the aimed situation:**

[image]

I already managed to solve with the ALL function to show the value in all the months but not only for July as I wanted. Here is the formula for that one:

Revenue:

```
=CALCULATE([Revenue],FILTER(ALL(Tbl_Period[Month_nr],Tbl_Period[Period_id]),Tbl_Period[Month_nr] = 3)) +CALCULATE([Revenue],FILTER(ALL(Tbl_Period[Month_nr],Tbl_Period[Period_id]),Tbl_Period[Month_nr] = 4))
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Is your `Tbl_Period` marked as a date table?

Comment: Actually the period table just contains the months with name like "Jun" and the order of the Month with numeric value. So it has 12 records only. It is because the fact table granularity is monthly not daily

Comment: Okay, then I think the proposed answer should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little bit blind, since you haven't mentioned the structure of your `Tbl_Period` table.

There are many helpful functions built into [dax](/questions/tagged/dax) that can save you a lot of work if you have a date table. One that would be relevant here is `PREVIOUSMONTH()`.

Working with just the information you have provided, you can get a measure to show the previous month's revenue like this:

```
LastMonthRevenue: = CALCULATE([Revenue], FILTER(ALL(Tbl_Period), Tbl_Period[Month_Nr] = MAX(Tbl_Period[Month_Nr]) - 1))
```

and then

```
TwoMonthsRevenue: = [Revenue] + [LastMonthRevenue]
```

Comment: Thanks it helped to understand the problem. My main issue was that although I tried the ALL function it didnt work with constant. The MAX function makes the connection with the pivot table which solve the riddle.